# Trigger/Open Link without opening it in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, href

I like to trigger/open a Link action (the link activates a LED) but I don't want to open the links website. It there an option to do it? Like opens the link in the background?

```
<a id='button' href="http://192.168.178.123/5/on:80">Button</a>
```

Is it possible with JS or other languages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just setting the href to "#" will stop the browser going anywhere.

Comment: Thank you - but I need the href IP address. With a press on the link it triggers an LED but I don't want to open the site behind the link. It should only activate the LED.

Comment: You can just store that in a data tag like this,

      <a id='button' href="#" data-ip="192.168.178.123/5/on:80">Button</a>

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript ajax call.

```
   var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhReq.open("GET", "http://192.168.178.123/5/on:80", false);
   xhReq.send(null);
   var serverResponse = xhReq.responseText;
```

Here is example how to bind function to button

`<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>`

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
     //Ajax call here
}
</script>
```

You can read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I implement it to a <a> or <button>?  What do I need to do?

Comment: If I try this the link won't open but there is no trigger/activation for my LED anymore :(

Answer (score 0):

try this

`<a id='button' href="http://192.168.178.123/5/on:80" onClick="fn(event)">button</a>`

`function fn(e){
  e.preventDefault();
}`

Comment: Thank you! If I try this the link won't open but there is no trigger/activation for my LED anymore :(

Answer (score 0):

You can [listen the event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp) that triggers when button's clicked and [send request](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp) using javascript.

```js
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  const url = 'http://192.168.178.123/5/on:80';
  request.open("GET", url);
  request.send();
});
```

```html
<a id='button' href="#">Button</a>
```

Comment: Thank you :) If I try this the link won't open but there is no trigger/activation for my LED anymore :(

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar for a different purpose and I did it this way:

in Head:

```
<script>
    function sleep(ms) { //wait function
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }

    async function ninjaLink() { //doing sneaky stuff
        var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe"); //Creating iFrame
        ifrm.setAttribute("src", "YOUR_URL"); // Setting iFrame's source
        ifrm.style.display = "none"; //Hiding iFrame
        document.body.appendChild(ifrm); //Adding iFrame
        await sleep(3000); //Giving the web page time to load
        document.body.removeChild(ifrm); //Removing iFrame
    }
</script>
```

in Body:

```
<a href="javascript:ninjaLink()">Link</a>
```

It opens the link in an hidden `iFrame` then destroys it.