# How to add a object to a users watch list via a link in Django

Tags: python, html, django, list, django-views

I have a website that recommends anime and I want each anime to have some text besides them as they appear, offering to add to a users 'list' which is a page where all anime in the users account-unique list will be shown. I have it working, and can add via the django admin but not via a button on the website.

models.py

```
class UserList(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    anime_in_list = models.ManyToManyField(Anime, blank=True)
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def userList(request):
    return render(request, 'userlist.html')

def add_to_userlist(request, anime_id):
    new_anime = get_object_or_404(Anime, pk=anime_id)
    #if UserList.objects.filter(user=request.user, anime_in_list=anime_id).exists():
        #message fail
    user_list, created = UserList.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    user_list.anime_in_list.add(new_anime)
    return render(request, "userlist.html")
```

on the html where the anime shows

```
<a href="{% url 'add_to_userlist' anime.id %}" role="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg">Add to list?</a>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
   ...
   path('userlist/', user_views.userList, name='userlist'),
   path('anime/', AnimeListView.as_view(), name='all-anime'),
   ...
]
```

but navigating to the anime html page now the error NoReverseMatch at /anime/
Reverse for 'add_to_userlist' not found. 'add_to_userlist' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

But I don't want to create a separate url to redirect them, I just want pressing the  to add to the users list, and if the user now navigates to their /userlist, they find that it has updated with the anime they clicked the link on.

Essentially it could be thought of like a shopping cart, where products exist and I just want to be able to click on them to add them to my list that works with the way I have models.py.
Any help would be super appreciated, ty

Comment: could you please share your urls.py ?

Comment: @ThiernoAmadouSow done sorry, I know there is no url currently for add_to_userlist but I didn't want to use another html page.

Comment: you want that through link you can invite user to watch animei together and probably chat

Comment: @sarangkkl um what?

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert, but you can try to return an empty HttpResponse

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
return HttpResponse('')
```

and on client side do a AJAX call to that view.
[Look Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55164528/trigger-open-link-without-opening-it-in-html)

or even better return a json which has included information about the proccess was succesfully or not and handle that result correctly on js side.

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
return JsonResponse({'status':'Anime already added'})
```

Needs JQuery

```
$.getJSON( "<django view url>", function(data) {
   console.log( "success" );
}).done(function() {
   console.log( "second success" );
})
.fail(function() {
  console.log( "error" );
})
.always(function() {
   console.log( "complete" );
});
```

Comment: I really appreciate the answer, but there must be a way without ajax / js to just grab the anime.id of the object where the button is and add it to the user who is logged in's user.userlist. I feel stumped on such a simple problem :(

Comment: The Problem is that a link is designed to redirect to a URL trough HTML, you want to click a link without such thing, you want that in Background a request is made to a backend, that is exactly what AJAX do :) Just create a js function with a AJAX call, its done in 5 minutes and better before u search for hours for super fancy way to solve it :)